# node.js problems with app.get() function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a site that uses mongojs.
I'm trying to use the code below, but once I run the site, it never gets into the app.get() parts, and the site ends up showing 500 error.
How can I make it respond to app.get function?

Thanks for the help!

```js
var express = require('express');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');

require('node-monkey').start({host: "127.0.0.1", port:"50500"}); //TODO: Delete

var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', ['usersData']);
var usersData = db.collection('usersData');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keys',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log("here");
});
```

Comment: On what line does the 500 get thrown?

Comment: It won't say,the site tries to load and then I get the following error:

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

Answer (score 2):

You have to start listen. Just add the line below :

```
  app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of reasons that can cause a 500 error in your case :

- Make sure you started a mongod instance (in the terminal)
- Try requiring all dependencies before doing `var app = express()` (the line right after should be moved up)
- Are the host URLs, ports, authentications and database names valid ?
- Your app.js structure is incomplete. When using ExpressJS, a certain skeleton is necessary for the app to work.

  ```
  // Dependencies
  var express = require('express');
  var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
  var session = require('express-session');
  var mongojs = require('mongojs');
  // DB
  var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', ['usersData']);
  var usersData = db.collection('usersData');
  // Start app
  var app = express();
  app.configure(function() {
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views'));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({
        secret: 'keys',
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized: true
    }));
    // etc...
  })
  // Routes
  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      console.log("here");
  });
  // App listen
  app.listen(3000);
  ```